# Deleting map objects from coreData using an alert VC, then saving

Tags: swift, core-data, mapkit

I have a map with pins that are loaded from coreData. In the annotation view, I have a button that brings up an alert view controller. From here the goal is to have the user be able to delete the annotation or edit the info and re-save.

To edit the info I will have the user segue to a new vc and edit info and save to coreData using try context.save() Unless you show me a better way!

The issue I am asking for help on is deleting right from the alert. I am able to delete the annotation from here but as soon as the map is reloaded the annotation is back because they are loading from coreData.
here is the code I am using in my alert

```
extension MapViewController: ExampleCalloutViewDelegate {
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didTapDetailsButton button: UIButton, for annotation: MKAnnotation) {



    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Edit or Delete", message: "Any changes are permenate!", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)



    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add more info and save on map ", style: .default, handler: {action in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveDetails", sender: self)}))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default, handler: {action in self.map.removeAnnotation(annotation)}))
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to delete the object in core data also -- context.delete(object), where object is the NSManagedObject.

Comment: Any advice on how to do this from the alert? I tried to include it in the action after removeAnnotation. It compiled but crashed when I click delete. Also not sure how to add context.save. I am very new to learning programing so any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: I have tried every solution I can find so far to get "object". The object that I want to delete is an annotation.  If I set object as! NSObject it crashes at runtime. I have also attempted multiple times to set or find an "objectID" with no success.